# populate bash command from a list passed as an argument to the function

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

I have a list which is passed as an argument to function. From this list I need to populate a bash command and execute it

```
lst = ['test01.gz','test02.gz','test03.gz','newtest01.gz','newtest02.gz','random.gz']

def populate_command(lst):
    cmd = 'cat {} {} > filename.gz'
    subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, check=True)
```

Here the `cat` command should be populated with `cat test01.gz test02.gz test03.gz > test.gz`. Likewise for `newtest01.gz` (`cat newtest01.gz newtest02.gz > newtest.gz`) and do nothing if there is only one `.gz` file (`random.gz`)

I am not able to populate the `cat` command with the arguments from list.
Any help would be appreciated

==================================

Edited code

came up with the following solution, but i guess there are too many for loops. Any other efficient way of doing this

i have a list of files 
`s3_files_list=[''test01.gz','test02.gz','test03.gz','newtest01.gz','newtest02.gz','random.gz'']`

from this i get the name of files which are split into multiple files like test01,test02 etc

`from typing import List`

`def find_split_files(temp_list) -> List[str]:
    main_lst=set()

    for x in temp_list:
        if x[:-3][-3:]!='000':
            main_lst.add(x[:-6])
    return main_lst`

`split_files=find_split_files(s3_files_list)`

split_files gives me ['test','newtest']

`def files_to_zip(split_files,s3_files_list):
    main_lst=[]
    for y in split_files:
        temp_lst=[]
        for x in s3_files_list:
            if x.startswith(y):
                temp_lst.append(x)
        main_lst.append(temp_lst)`

Main_lst returns [['test01.gz','test02.gz','test03.gz'],['newtest01.gz','newtest02.gz']]

`def populate_command(main_lst): 
    for p in main_lst:
        cmd = 'cat '
        for f in p:
            cmd = cmd + f + ' '
        cmd = cmd + ' > ' + f[:-6]+'.gz'
        print(f'command is {cmd}')
       subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, check=True)`

Comment: "I am not able to populate the cat command with the arguments from list" - well, you haven't even tried. Some questions to consider: how would the function know which file names should be passed to the `cat` command? (Why not stuff everything in `lst` there, for example?) How would the function know where to write the result? As in, what file name should be after the `>`?

Comment: Parsing that list is not going to be very easy. If you could get your data in the form of `[['test01.gz', 'test02.gz', 'test03.gz'], ['newtest01.gz', 'newtest02.gz'], ['random.gz']]` (or even better, something like `[(['test01.gz', 'test02.gz', 'test03.gz'], 'test.gz'), (['newtest01.gz', 'newtest02.gz'], 'newtest.gz'), (['random.gz'], None)]`), then it would be a lot easier to do what you want. Let us know if you are able to do this in your case or not.

Comment: It seems this question is made of two questions. Solving one at the time is a good advice, and you might be able to do it on your own then.

Comment: You don't really need the shell. `with open(outfile, 'w') as f: run(['cat'] + infiles, stdout=f)`. The hard part, as nog642 points out, is splitting your input list appropriately. You probably don't even need to use `subprocess`; you can open the input files and write them to the output file in Python itself, without using `cat`.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the lst using the for statement and buildup the cmd string as shown:

```
> def populate_command(lst):
>     cmd = 'cat '
>     for f in lst:
>         cmd = cmd + f + ' '
>     cmd = cmd + ' > filename.gz'
>     subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, check=True)
```